# Use Spring Bean as Composer

Tags: spring, zk, zul

I have a zul like this:

```
<window id="modwin" sclass="modalWindowCitas"  title="Cita" apply="com.company.app.mvc.zul.m.diana.f1.ModalCitaController">
```

**ModalCitaController** is my Composer.

When the zul opens, ZK create new instance of the composer, but I want apply a Spring interceptor to my Composer.

That's why I need to use a bean, if ZK creates new instance the interceptor don't work.

I want apply PerformanceMonitorInterceptor to measure the execution times only in local enviroment

Is there any way to do it?
Something like this:

```
<window apply="{mySpringBean}">
```

Answer (score 0):

ZK already provides some tool to monitor an ajax request, Please refer to:

- https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Performance_Monitoring/Event_Interceptors
- https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Performance_Monitoring/Performance_Meters

About making a composer as a spring bean please refer to [this doc](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Integration/Middleware_Layer/Spring#Warning:_Register_a_Composer_.28or_ViewModel.29_as_a_Spring_bean)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a the variable resolver that ZK provides. When no other resolver find the expression it will looking for beans with the name.

Just put this in zk.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver</listener-class>
</listener>
```

For more informations: https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Spring_Essentials/Working_with_ZK_Spring/Working_with_ZK_Spring_Core/Using_Spring_Variable_Resolver